# Cross matching and deleting rows from a csv using data from text file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, text, matching

I have a problem that I do not know how to achieve currently. I need to remove rows from a csv dependant on matching data from two columns.

So if the text file reads:

```
London
James Smith, John Oliver, John-Smith-Harrison

Paris
Hermione, Trevor Wilson

New York city
Charlie Chaplin, Ned Stark, Thoma' Becket, Ryan-Dover
```

Then the csv would remove a row based on matching the City name with the second column as well as matching the name in the 9th column.

I expect this is relatively easy function. If someone could provide an example of how to do this it would be greatly appreciated. Kind regards AEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. It assumes the csv file is called 'input.csv' and it writes to a file 'output.csv' rows that don't match 'Paris', 'Trevor Wilson'.

It uses a `grouper` recipe from the [itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to combine the rows into groups of 3.

Note that the syntax of csv files varies greatly as there is no well defined standard. It's worth looking at the docs for the `csv` module if your real input file does not match the example you have posted. For instance, I have used the `skipinitialspace` option to tell the parser to ignore white space immediately after the delimiter.

```
import csv
from itertools import *

# see recipies section in itertools docs
# http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

with open('input.csv') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_f:
        output = csv.writer(output_f)
        for city, names, blank in grouper(data, 3, []):
            if not (city[0] == 'Paris' and 'Trevor Wilson' in names):
                output.writerow(city)
                output.writerow(names)
                output.writerow('')
```